# UILabel with tag, can't set text

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I'm having a problem with labels. I have a couple of labels that I need to change with help of tags. I do this in my code, but it gives an exception 
`-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
This is my code:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:0];

label.text = @"empty";
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are not getting back a UILabel. Try changing your tags to higher numbers. 0 is the default tag for anything to your view will have that tag first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every view's tag is default to 0.

> tag
>
> An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your
>   application.
>
> @property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag
>
> Discussion
>
> The default value is 0.
>   You can set the value of this tag and use that value to identify the
>   view later.

Your `viewWithTag` will return your `self.view`. So you will get a `UIView` instead of a `UILabel` and your app will crash. See `viewWithTag`'s definition:

> viewWithTag:
>
> Returns the view whose tag matches the specified value.
>
> `- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag`
>   Parameters
>
> *tag*
>
> The tag value to search for. Return Value The view in the receiver’s hierarchy whose
>   tag property matches the value in the tag parameter.
>
> Discussion
>
> This method searches **the current view** and all of its
>   subviews for the specified view.

So the solution for you is you need to specify unique `tag` for every label. And then use `viewWithTag:` and give the tag you specified.

Comment: Thanks, so I can use any tag but 0?

Comment: You can indeed 0. But every `UIView`'s tag is default to 0 if you don't specify a non-zero tag. You will have a lot views whose tag is 0. This is definitely not what you want. Sure you can use 0 but a non-zero tag is infinitely better.